# Got warning in mysql and effect to other app such as zabbix

Tags: mysql, warnings

I got mysql warning in log file

```
2016-01-26 15:24:03 10584 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
```

What is that and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong config!
please use

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0  #for all IP's
```